# Process called kernel_task has high CPU and memory usage. What I can do to fix it?

Tags: macos, upgrade

After upgrade my version of Mac OS X version to 10.9 (Mavericks), I have a process called `kernel_task` with high CPU and memory usage, what I can do to fix it?

I found so many issues and solutions in forums and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kernel_task` process is the core of the operating system. It is normal that it reserves a large chunk of memory for itself. Why it is consuming high CPU resources is not unusual and difficult to answer. However, the consumption is typically related to other software running and performing intensive I/O tasks. This could be because Spotlight is indexing the drive or there is a large file copy or networking tasks underway.

A behavior of Mac OS X's kernel is that if the temperatures of the hardware rise above safe thresholds the kernel_task will start to reserve great bulks of time on the CPUs doing nothing in order to lower the temperature. Perhaps that's what you were seeing. After an OS upgrade many processes are invoked to re-index content, etc.

More investigation is required to understand the hows and whys intensive kernel processing.